# Why contents of matrix implemented as vector of vector not changing?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, c++14

I was trying to rotate the matrix inplace for an online programming challenge.I chose to implement the matrix as vector of vector and performed the transpose and printed it. But my problem is the contents of the matrix are not changing after transpose. Can someone please tell what wrong am i doing? The following is the code i have written. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<iomanip>

// matrix dimension
int const Dim {4};

auto Fill = [] (auto& mat)
{
  auto c = 1;
  for(auto i=0; i<Dim; ++i)
    for(auto j=0; j<Dim; ++j)
        mat[i][j] = c++;
};

auto Print = [] (auto const& mat)
{
  for(auto i=0; i<Dim; ++i)
  {
    for(auto j=0; j<Dim; ++j)
     std::cout << std::setw(3) << mat[i][j];
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
};

auto Transpose = [] (auto& mat)
{
  for(auto i=0; i<Dim; ++i)
    for(auto j=0; j<Dim; ++j)
        std::swap(mat[i][j], mat[j][i]);
};

auto main()->int
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat(Dim,
                   std::vector<int>(Dim));

  Fill(mat);
  cout << "Before Transpose: \n";
  Print(mat);
  Transpose(mat);
  cout << "After Transpose: \n";
  Print(mat);
  return 0;
} 
==================================
Output:
Before Transpose:
1    2   3    4
5    6   7    8
9   10  11   12
13  14  15   16

After Transpose:
1    2   3    4
5    6   7    8
9   10  11   12
13  14  15   16
```

Comment: You swap the array elements twice. Use `for(auto i=0; i<Dim; ++i)` `for(auto j=i+1; j<Dim; ++j)` `std::swap(mat[i][j], mat[j][i]);` - focus on `j=i+1`

Comment: A small matrix, say 4x4 (like yours) coupled with printing the i, j, and the matrix itself after each element swap (yes, in your case that would be 16 dumps) will clearly show where things started to unravel, as Rabbid describes.

Comment: Thank you Rabbid76 for pointing out my silly mistake.